# I need to reprint my input but only my sentinel is being printed

Tags: python

```
sentinel = "Done"
input_string(str(input("Enter strings (end with DONE):")))

while input_string != sentinel:
    input_string= str(input())
    
#remove duplicates   
res = []
for i in input_string:
    if i not in res:
        res.append(i)

print("\nUnique list:")
print(input_string)
```

This is the expected output

```
Sample I/O
Enter strings (end with DONE):
the
old
man
and
the
sea
DONE
Unique list:
the
old
man
and sea
```

Comment: Please add a language tag when you ask a question. I'm guessing this is Python, so I've added the tag for you - please correct if I've geuessed wrongly.

Comment: you should directly add your strings to `set` if insertion order doesn't matter

Comment: Why do you need it end with DONE? Why not just type all the string and then press enter instead of type one word by one?

Comment: No need to convert input to `str` it is already a string

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
sentinel = "DONE"
input_string = str(input("Enter strings (end with " + sentinel + "):"))

input_list = [input_string]

while input_string != sentinel:
    input_string = str(input())
    input_list.append(input_string)

#remove duplicates   
res = []
for i in input_list:
    if not i in res and i != sentinel:
        res.append(i)

print("\nUnique list:")
for i in res:
    print(i) # So it will output one by one
```

It should output:

```
python.exe test.py
Enter strings (end with DONE):the
old
man
and
the
sea
DONE

Unique list:
the
old
man
and
sea
```

If you don't care about the order, you can use `set`. It's much easier:

```
sentinel = "DONE"
input_string = str(input("Enter strings (end with " + sentinel + "):"))

input_list = [input_string]

while input_string != sentinel:
    input_string = str(input())
    input_list.append(input_string)

#remove duplicates   
res = list(set(input_list[0:-1]))

print("\nUnique list:")
for i in res:
    print(i) # So it will output one by one
```

The output should be:

```
python.exe test.py
Enter strings (end with DONE):the
old
man
and
the
sea
DONE

Unique list:
sea
and
the
old
man
```

Small question: Why do you need it end with DONE? Why not just type all the string and then press enter instead of type one word by one?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `input_string` is not a list but a value which is reassigned with each input. Because of this, 1) the `for` loop did not quite do what you intended it to do and 2) `print(input_string)` was simply printing the last user input, namely "Done".

The following should do the work:

```
sentinel = "DONE"
input_list = []
input_string = str(input("Enter strings (end with DONE):"))
input_list.append(input_string)

while input_string != sentinel:
    input_string = str(input())
    input_list.append(input_string)

#remove duplicates   
res = []
for i in input_list:
    if i not in res and i != "DONE":
        res.append(i)

print("\nUnique list:")
print(res)
```

PS: In my snippet, I've changed `sentinel` to "DONE" to ensure consistency between `sentinel` and the default message of `input_string`.

Comment: Thank you!!!! but in order to print out the first input you need to add input_list.append(input_string) after input_list = []

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit shorted code and cleaner, to add the new word only to the list, so you do not need extra checking at the end, and removing extra code not necessary:

```
sentinel = "DONE"
unique_list = []

input_string = input("Enter strings (end with " + sentinel + "):")

while input_string != sentinel:
    if input_string not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(input_string)
    input_string = input()

print("\nUnique list:")
#print(input_list)
for i in unique_list:
    print(i)
```